# How to separate when vector objects of the same type are shared in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, object, vector

In general, for variables of the same type, A will not be affected even if B changes after entering B into A.

However, in case of Vector type object, if B is input to A object and B.clear () or B.removeAllElements() is executed, A is also initialized to null value.

Please explain why this is happening
Also, how can I disconnect shared objects of vector objects A and B?

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A = 1;
        int B;
        B = A;
        A = 0;

        Vector<String> goPathNode = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<String> tempGoPath = new Vector<String>();

        tempGoPath.add("A");
        tempGoPath.add("B");
        tempGoPath.add("C");
        //goPathNode.add("A");
        //goPathNode.add("B");
        //goPathNode.add("C");
        goPathNode = tempGoPath;
        tempGoPath.clear();
        //goPathNode.removeAllElements();

      }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code.  Cut and paste it into the question itself.

Comment: Why? I used an image to show how the results came out. Is there a problem with clicking images? 
Anyway, I fixed it as you wished so someone could solve the problem.

Comment: Primitive ints have different semantics then reference types. In your example, by doing that final assignment, you end up with ONE vector object, but you have TWO references (variables) pointing towards that one object. That is like: you have a first name and a last name. You can be addressed by either of that names. But it is still just one person.

Comment: *"Why?"* - Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)

Comment: I understand, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable goPathNode becomes reference of tempGoPath. So if you clear tempGoPath then goPathNode will get cleared too.

Call clone() function if u want them to be seperate

```
goPathNode = tempGoPath.clone();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
If run it as you told me, the problem is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Vector <String>". 
So I solved it by modifying "goPathNode = (Vector <String>) tempGoPath.clone ();".